# Spring Data: Query DTOs with QueryDSL predicates

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, dto, entitygraph

I am using QueryDSL to query/filter entities (Document):

```
   public interface DocumentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Document, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Document>
```

Then I build QueryDSL Predicates and use method findAll to filter results:

```
   Predicate predicate = myBuilder.buildPredicate(myUserFilterObject)
   Page<Document> page = documentRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable)
```

It works well except for that I need to avoid N+1 selects (JPA). Is there any way to query DTOs instead of entities (but still use QueryDSL predicates) or is it possible to apply EntityGraphs here (didn't work for me)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Spring Data JPA 2.1 onwards you can use `@EntityGraph` annotation.

```
public interface DocumentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Document, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Document> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "name_of_collection_to_load" })
    Page<Document> findAll(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable)
}
```

Comment: Ok, it works *somehow*, but it doesn't solve OneToOne relations (in multiple layers) - it still adds additional select - if I use EntityGraph to force loading of OneToOne object (let's call it directOneToOneChild) in main query, it works, but if this onedirectOneToOneChild has another OneToOne relationship, there are still additional N selects.

Comment: Ok, I missed NamedAttributeNode/subgraphs, it works then.